# Is the voltage rating printed on capacitors always DC?

Tags: capacitor, identification, maximum-ratings, ratings

Are there any cases where the voltage value printed on the capacitor is actually AC, like on film caps designed specifically for AC/Pulse operation? Or is the value printed on the capacitor always DC?

Comment: It's a pointless question because anyone seriously considering a capacitor for AC applications should be interested in the data sheet information. In other words, make sure that what component you have in your hand is identifiable and has a data sheet. It's the part number and component provenance that is important.

Comment: It is not a pointless question when you want to recap an old device and you don't know anything about the capacitors beside what is printed on them.

Comment: If the capacitor cannot be traced to its origin then, you look into the circuitry that surrounds it and work out what type of capacitor is needed for that circuit. If you felt that you can bypass this process with a guess then good luck to you but, if you ever go for a job as an EE, don't tell the interviewers that you might be prepared to take short cuts in this respect.

Comment: I know the type. It is metalized polypropylene film cap for AC/Pulse operation. I just don't know if the voltage rating printed on it is AC or DC.

Comment: Then figure out the circuit and work out what voltage these capacitors might be subject to. There are no valid safe short cuts on the circuit you are describing (despite your reaction above receiving upvotes from the hobby brigade / bodgers).

Comment: I find recapping can be a problem, I just replace the bad ones. I hope you have good soldering skills.

Comment: The thing is, if one capacitor leaked or failed, the others are also somewhat likely to fail soon. And if the wrong capacitor fails, it might do a lot of damage to the device.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*AC rating printed on capacitor. Image source: Amazon via Google image search for "AC capacitor".*

[image]

*AC rating printed on ceramic capacitor. Image source: Alibaba via Google image search for "AC ceramic capacitor.*

Comment: Yes only AC plastic caps are rated for Vac?  Maybe other old technology AC caps as well. (Paper)

Comment: The voltage rating for ceramic caps?

Comment: Interesting! When the rating is in AC, it is always marked as such (...V AC or ...V~)? And when there is just ...V with no additional makings, it is safe to assume that it is DC?

Comment: @HungryBear, I wouldn't assume anything if it's not marked. Check the datasheet.

Comment: Motor start and run capacitors usually have AC voltage ratings too.

Comment: @Transistor I'm recapping an old deivce with no schematics available, so I have to rely on what is printed on the caps unfortunately

Comment: Then you'll have to reverse engineer the circuits to try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I guess getting the highest voltage rating for the given capacitance that would physically fit the circuit would be the safest option